# Find $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ when $A_n = \big(a,b - \frac{b-a}{2n}\big]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The solution is fairly obvious but I have a hard time convincing myself that I can justify each step instead of just *knowing* the answer. Here's what I have:

1. Note that $\forall n\in\Bbb N$, we have $A_{n} \cup A_{n+1} = A_{n+1}$
2. Therefore, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}A_n$
3. Using the definition of $A_n$, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (a,b-\frac{b-a}{2n}] = (a , b - \lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon] = (a,b)$

For some context, I am in the first week of a Statistics masters and have no formal math background. Therefore, I am not completely sure if my proposed steps are omitting/assuming any crucial information or perhaps misusing notation.

My specific gripes comes with steps 1 and 3:

In the first case, would I be expected to prove that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$? I could provide a specific breakdown of that logic statements defining the **lhs** and **rhs** statements to show their equivalence, but this seems overkill.

For the last step, I am completely stumped regarding how to handle the limit and interval boundaries. My calculus I training tells me that because $\lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0}\epsilon = 0$, the interval should evaluate to $(a,b]$ but I know that logically that is wrong. However, I can't come up with a statement to justify the difference.

Comment: Instead of trying to take limits of sets, simply show both inclusions. Show that an arbitrary element of the union is in the interval $(a,b)$. Tthen show that an arbitrary element of $(a,b)$ is in $A_n$ for some $n$, hence is in the union.

Comment: Do you know Archimedean Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following approach (which was also suggested by @quasi).

First, let us observe that for each $n$, $$\frac{b-a}{2n}>0$$ and so 
$$b-\frac{b-a}{2n}<b$$
implying that  $A_n\subset (a,b)$ and hence
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\subset (a,b).\tag 1$$

Next, let $x\in (a,b)$. Using the Archimedean Property, we can find $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\frac{1}{m}<\frac{2(b-x)}{b-a}.$$
This means that 
$$a<x<b-\frac{b-a}{2m}$$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$. Hence,
$$x\in\bigg(a,b-\frac{b-a}{2m}\bigg)=A_m.$$
But 
$$A_m\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n.$$
This proves that 
$$(a,b)\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n.\tag 2$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=(a,b).$$

**NOTE:** It should be noted that $b\notin A_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: I actually don't know the Archimedean Property but I see there are plenty of resources online to learn more about it, so I guess I'll be coming back to this over the next few days. Regarding my proposed solution, would you consider it insufficient? Sloppy but sufficient? I'd like to be made aware of any gaps in my reasoning. Thank you!